# I need to create a dummy network adapter with a specific.customizable MAC address

Tags: network-adapter, mac-address, loopback

I am trying to put a band aid on a very flawed piece of software, and need to create a dummy network adapter in Windows that will have a MAC address **matching** one of my real network adapters.

This dummy network adapter never needs to be in a connected state.  It doesn't have to be reachable on the network, and no traffic needs to flow through it.  It never needs to be assigned an IP address.

I've been trying to leverage a Microsoft Loopback Adapter, but am running into a limitation with the acceptable NetworkAddresses.  It seems to only accept being assigned a MAC address from the accepted local range (ex: 02-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx).  An example of a MAC I need to emulate would be 9C-B6-D0-B8-6D-D7.

Can anyone point me towards another method of creating a dummy network adapter, or alternatively a way of overriding the Loopback adapters local MAC limitation?

Thanks in advance